# Type mismatch error in Scala code

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve the Project Euler, Problem 5. I have found many solutions on the Internet but I'm trying my own version (not so functional approach). I am stuck with an error: `type mismatch found :Unit Required:Boolean`.

```
object Euler5 {

  def divby1to10(input: Int): Boolean = {
    for (i <- 1 to 10) { // type mismatch found :Unit Required:Boolean
      if (input % i == 0)
        false
      else true
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(divby1to10(5))
  }
}
```

If I remove the `:Boolean`, the code compiles but the output is `()`. Can someone help me to figure out what is wrong with this code and give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what your `for` loop is doing.

```
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  if (input % i == 0)
    false
  else true
}
```

You're looping ten times and producing ten different results. Now, I imagine you want these `false` and `true` values to propagate outward, but what if some of the iteration steps return `false` and others `true`? You haven't specified how you want them combined. For this reason, in Scala, an (imperative) `for` loop always returns `()`. I think what you want is

```
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  if (input % i != 0)
    return false // Definitely doesn't divide them all, so return false now
  // If it does divide, continue the loop
}
// If we get to this point, it divided them all, so return true
true
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is what I was actually looking for

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `for` loop has return type `Unit` and in your function definition you are requiring `Boolean`.

A more functional approach to express your logic could be:

```
def divby1to10(input: Int): Boolean = (1 to 10).forall(input % _ == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, unlike other programming languages e.g. Java control flow constructs like **if**, **for** and **while** are expressions which return value of some type.

In given specific example your **for** statement returns **Unit** because of the following statement in [Scala language specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) which states:

> A for loop for (p <- e) e′ is translated to e.foreach { case p => e′ }

In your example e has a type **Range** (more specifically - Range.Inclusive).
For that type **foreach** is defined so that it returns Unit. As a result your entire for expression produces Unit. Finally as your **for** expression is the last statement of your function the function itself also returns Unit, hence the error.

Normally foreach constructs instead of returning some values are used to produce side effects on each generated value **p**, e.g. print something into console hence the return type Unit. So for your specific task probably it doesn't fit well. As were explained in other answers there are several ways to rewrite your logic so that your function returns boolean value.